# XML query with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have an xml document (it's a config file for a game) that looks something like:

```
<properties>
  ...
  <settings>
    <fooBar value="abc"/>
    <uffDa value="1.23"/>
    ...
  </settings>
  ...
</properties>
```

I'm trying to get all of the settings printed in a format like

```
fooBar abc
uffDa 1.23
...
```

I've used xmlstarlet to query a few attributes but that's it. I don't have any experience working with xml and even with the help docs I had some difficulty just figuring out that much.

The best I've been able to do is narrow it down to the settings with

```
xml sel -t -c "/properties/settings" <xml file>
```

but that includes the parent settings tags in the output. I also tried

```
xml sel -t -c "/properties/settings/*" <xml file>
```

which didn't include the settings tags in the output, but it didn't include any line-breaks either.

Technically, either output could be used for what I'm trying to do (compare the settings from two config files) but I'm hoping to get something more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
xml sel -T -t -m "//properties/settings//*"  -v "name()" -o " " -v "@value"  -nl yourfile.xml
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Though the `-nl` should be `-n` or `--nl `. I'm curious about the double slashes though, because I get the same result when using just single slashes.

Comment: @You're right - `-nl` shouldn't work, but it does....